# is it possible to return the results of a report using the analytics api via SFRestRequest method?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfrestrequest

I have built an app using the Salesforce Mobile iOS SDK V2.0 and I would like to be able to display the results of certain reports to the user. Is it possible to return the results of a report using the analytics api via `SFRestRequest` method? Furthermore, if it is possible can you provide sample code?

Comment: is SFRestRequest you are using in java? Analytics api returns json data so you should be able to get in  iOS SDK V2.0

Comment: I only know how to create a SOQL and use the SRestRequest method to send this off and get a JSON result which I then put into an array, however I don't know what other methods are available or how to modify the method in order to be able to get the JSON returned. @ShebinMathew would you be able to illustrate with code?

Comment: Do you know using REST API ? then our job is so easy...

Comment: indeed but I need to sue the SDK V2.0 for iOS

Comment: You can use REST API in  mobile for sure. Once you have done let me know I can help you ok